# Angular 2 - Passing an argument to a custom pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have a created a pipe which can receive 2 arugments, but I'm not sure how I can sent them.

here's my pipe:

```
export class TranslationPipe implements PipeTransform {

    private capitalize: boolean;

    constructor(
        private translationService: TranslationService
    ) {
        this.capitalize = true;
    }

    transform(key: string, capitalize?: boolean): string {
        if (typeof capitalize !== "undefined" || capitalize !== null)
            this.capitalize = capitalize;

        return this.translationService.getTranslation(key, this.capitalize);
    }
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
{{ 'searchquery' | translate }}
```

this works, but how can I pass `capitlize = false` aswell? I've tried some googling but I can't really find any example the way I want to implement it (maybe I'm doing it wrong?)

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{{ 'searchquery' | translate:false }}

{{ 'searchquery' | translate:'toUsEn' }}
```

Comment: this worked, how do I do this if i want to pass a string? `{{ 'searchquery' | translate:stringvalue }}` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Nicolas, I know that you may already solved your problem but, since I had the same doubt, I think someone may read this too. So you've just forgot to put your stringvalue between single quotes:      
{{ 'searchquery' | translate:'stringvalue' }}